# MoviePy not able to super-impose hindi text properly on Image

Tags: python, imagemagick, moviepy, hindi

I'm developing a python program to generate video with hindi text super imposed on an image. Well it does the job upto some extent but at some places there are mistakes (typo sort of). When I checked the input string, its perfectly fine. But when the video is processed, the text goes wrong.

I've already checked using `string_to_display.encode('utf-8')` and setting  different hindi fonts like `txt_clip.append(TextClip(string_to_display.encode('utf-8'), font='Mangal'))`

For example consider this string and its corresponding output, the bold texts are erroneous ones:

> ​Rajasthan Teacher Jobs 2022: खुशखबरी! **राजस्थान** 32000 **शिक्षक भर्ती** की
> अंतिम **तिथि बढ़ी**, देखें **नोटिस**

[image]

Comment: Did you try the font in some other app (word processor, etc..)?

Comment: It only works when windows input type is selected as Hindi otherwise it don't bother about the font and prints in English only. I tested changing windows input type before executing but it gave the same result. Thanks by the way

Comment: Were you able to fix this? If yes then please provide an answer to this quest as it will be very helpful for me.